# How to understand group elements with only a trivial irreducible representation?

Tags: electromagnetism, condensed-matter, symmetry, group-theory, representation-theory

From the [database](https://www.cryst.ehu.es/) of crystallographic groups, I found a magnetic point group shown below ([link](https://www.cryst.ehu.es/cgi-bin/cryst/programs/corepresentations_point.pl?magnum=3.3.8)).

Let's look at the first (1) and third (2') elements. 1 is the identity element; 2' means $\pi$-rotation and time reversal. But the 1D irrep is always the same $1$ for these two elements.

How to understand this? I naively think they are different symmetry operations; there should at least be some irrep (e.g., the 1D sign irrep with $\pm1$) that distinguishes them. Is there any physical reason for this?

[image]